# How to compare two dataframes with different levels of precision in one column

Tags: python, dataframe

I am creating a dataframe of results by comparing df_one to df_two with the code below.

```
df_results = pd.DataFrame(df_one.eq(db_two))
```

This works great, but one of the columns in df_one has a float with a precision level of 9, and the other has a precision level of 12. I want the test to return true if the first 9 numbers after the decimal are equal, even if the last 3 are not.

So I end up comparing something like the two values below.

```
Column One              Column Two
------------------      ------------------
42.123456789            42.123456789012
```

I know I can change the precision level for the display with a set_option setting.

```
pd.set_option("precision", 9)
```

Unfortunately, this is only for display, so it doesn't affect the comparison done by the eq function.

Any help is appreciated in advance.

Comment: Try applying `round(x, 9)` to columns two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @duncster94 says, try:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[42.123456789,42.123456789012]], columns=list('AB'))
>>> df[df.A==round(df.B, 10)]
           A          B
0  42.123457  42.123457
>>>
```

Or you could even use [`math.isclose`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isclose)

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> from math import isclose
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[42.123456789,42.123456789012]], columns=list('AB'))
>>> df[df.apply(lambda row: isclose(row.A, row.B, rel_tol=1e-12), axis=1)]
           A          B
0  42.123457  42.123457
>>> df[df.apply(lambda row: isclose(row.A, row.B, rel_tol=1e-13),axis=1)]
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [A, B]
Index: []
```